# Pythonic way to explode a bill of material (BOM) with Phyton to get a beautiful tree? I would like other solutions in pure and nice pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas

### My ugly code:

I just wanted to do it with dictionaries and get a json. But I only succeeded using Pandas and Treelib. Could any good soul give me an instruction on how to get the same result in a simpler way? My function became very time expensive and heavy, it takes a long time to return the expected result.
I put this in kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/luizgustavorodrigues/bom-explosion-tree-test

```python
import pandas as pd
from treelib import Node, Tree
from collections.abc import Iterable

### db_name = "Everest_simulator.db"
### conn = sql.connect(db_name)
### query_components = f'SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(cd_item)) AS item, LTRIM(RTRIM(parent)) AS parent, LTRIM(RTRIM(child)) AS child, ghost, qty FROM Processo'
### df = pd.read_sql(query_components, conn)
### query_items = f'SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(cd_item)) AS item, LTRIM(RTRIM(descricao)) AS description FROM Item'
### df_items = pd.read_sql(query_items, conn)

### Is there a way to get the result directly from SQL?

dict_components = [{'parent': 'part1', 'child': 'part2', 'ghost': 'y', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part1', 'child': 'part3', 'ghost': 'y', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part1', 'child': 'part4', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part2', 'child': 'part5', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 2},
 {'parent': 'part3', 'child': 'part6', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 3},
 {'parent': 'part3', 'child': 'part7', 'ghost': 'y', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part7', 'child': 'part8', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 4},
 {'parent': 'part7', 'child': 'part9', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 2},
 {'parent': 'part7', 'child': 'part10', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part7', 'child': 'part11', 'ghost': 'y', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part11', 'child': 'part12', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 3},
 {'parent': 'part11', 'child': 'part13', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 2},
 {'parent': 'part11', 'child': 'part14', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 2},
 {'parent': 'part1', 'child': 'part15', 'ghost': 'y', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part15', 'child': 'part16', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 2},
 {'parent': 'part15', 'child': 'part17', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part15', 'child': 'part18', 'ghost': 'y', 'qty': 1},
 {'parent': 'part18', 'child': 'part19', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 5},
 {'parent': 'part18', 'child': 'part20', 'ghost': 'n', 'qty': 2}]

df_components = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_components)

dict_items = [{'item': 'part1', 'description': 'part1 description'},
 {'item': 'part2', 'description': 'part2 description'},
 {'item': 'part3', 'description': 'part3 description'},
 {'item': 'part4', 'description': 'part4 description'},
 {'item': 'part5', 'description': 'part5 description'},
 {'item': 'part6', 'description': 'part6 description'},
 {'item': 'part7', 'description': 'part7 description'},
 {'item': 'part8', 'description': 'part8 description'},
 {'item': 'part9', 'description': 'part9 description'},
 {'item': 'part10', 'description': 'part10 description'},
 {'item': 'part11', 'description': 'part11 description'},
 {'item': 'part12', 'description': 'part12 description'},
 {'item': 'part13', 'description': 'part13 description'},
 {'item': 'part14', 'description': 'part14 description'},
 {'item': 'part15', 'description': 'part15 description'},
 {'item': 'part16', 'description': 'part16 description'},
 {'item': 'part17', 'description': 'part17 description'},
 {'item': 'part18', 'description': 'part18 description'},
 {'item': 'part19', 'description': 'part19 description'},
 {'item': 'part20', 'description': 'part20 description'}]

df_items =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_items)

def get_tree_children(item_number, version=""):
    used = [item_number] # work arround to not duplicate parent nodes
    item_filter = df_components["parent"].str.strip() == item_number
    children = df_components.loc[item_filter] # Filter from thousand of data only the needed item
    for x in children.itertuples(index=True, name="Pandas"):
        if isinstance(x, Iterable): # received an Error message without this
            if x.child in used:
                pass
            else:
                used.append(x.child)
                child_item = df_items.loc[df_items['item'] == x.child] # to get the child description on df_items
                tree.create_node(
                    f"{x.child} - {child_item.description.item()} - G:{x.ghost}\t\t\t\t qty: {x.qty}",
                    f"{x.child}",
                    parent = f"{x.parent}",
                )
                get_tree_children(x.child, version="")
    return tree

item_to_tree = "part3" # interested part
tree = Tree() # create a tree named tree
tree.create_node(f"{item_to_tree}", f"{item_to_tree}") # create tree root
get_tree_children(item_to_tree) # call to get_tree_children function passing interested part
tree.show()
tree.to_json()
```

#### Result:

My returned tree:

```
part3
├── part6 - part6 description - G:n              qty: 3
└── part7 - part7 description - G:y              qty: 1
    ├── part10 - part10 description - G:n                qty: 1
    ├── part11 - part11 description - G:y                qty: 1
    │   ├── part12 - part12 description - G:n                qty: 3
    │   ├── part13 - part13 description - G:n                qty: 2
    │   └── part14 - part14 description - G:n                qty: 2
    ├── part8 - part8 description - G:n              qty: 4
    └── part9 - part9 description - G:n              qty: 2
```

#### My returned json:

```json
{
  "part3": {
    "children": [
      "part6 - part6 description - G:n\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 3",
      {
        "part7 - part7 description - G:y\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 1": {
          "children": [
            "part10 - part10 description - G:n\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 1",
            {
              "part11 - part11 description - G:y\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 1": {
                "children": [
                  "part12 - part12 description - G:n\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 3",
                  "part13 - part13 description - G:n\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 2",
                  "part14 - part14 description - G:n\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 2"
                ]
              }
            },
            "part8 - part8 description - G:n\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 4",
            "part9 - part9 description - G:n\\t\\t\\t\\t qty: 2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### I expected to get out of this:

"Ghosts" are not bought. Only your children.
"Not ghosts" are bought and your children (if it exists) are not. The children of non-ghosts are only shown in the BOM for reference.

#### ***df_components*** - Components dataframe

| parent | child | ghost | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| part1 | part2 | y | 1 |
| part1 | part3 | y | 1 |
| part1 | part4 | n | 1 |
| part2 | part5 | n | 2 |
| part3 | part6 | n | 3 |
| part3 | part7 | y | 1 |
| part7 | part8 | n | 4 |
| part7 | part9 | n | 2 |
| part7 | part10 | n | 1 |
| part7 | part11 | y | 1 |
| part11 | part12 | n | 3 |
| part11 | part13 | n | 2 |
| part11 | part14 | n | 2 |
| part1 | part15 | y | 1 |
| part15 | part16 | n | 2 |
| part15 | part17 | n | 1 |
| part15 | part18 | y | 1 |
| part18 | part19 | n | 5 |
| part18 | part20 | n | 2 |

#### ***df_items*** - Items dataframe

I get the items description in this table. The primary key is the item.

| item | description |
| --- | --- |
| part1 | part1 description |
| part2 | part2 description |
| part3 | part3 description |
| part4 | part4 description |
| part5 | part5 description |
| part6 | part6 description |
| part7 | part7 description |
| part8 | part8 description |
| part9 | part9 description |
| part10 | part10 description |
| part11 | part11 description |
| part12 | part12 description |
| part13 | part13 description |
| part14 | part14 description |
| part15 | part15 description |
| part16 | part16 description |
| part17 | part17 description |
| part18 | part18 description |
| part19 | part19 description |
| part20 | part20 description |

### To this:

#### BOM for part3:

|  | lvl | part1_bom | description | qty | ghost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | part3 | part3 description | 1 | y |
| 1 | 1 | --part6 | part6 description | 3 | n |
| 2 | 1 | --part7 | part7 description | 1 | y |
| 3 | 2 | ----part10 | part10 description | 1 | n |
| 4 | 2 | ----part11 | part11 description | 1 | y |
| 5 | 3 | ------part12 | part11 description | 3 | n |
| 6 | 3 | ------part13 | part11 description | 2 | n |
| 7 | 3 | ------part14 | part11 description | 2 | n |
| 8 | 2 | ----part8 | part8 description | 4 | n |
| 9 | 2 | ----part9 | part9 description | 5 | n |

### And this:

According to those rules for ghost items, this is the result for purchases:

#### Parts to buy:

|  | part1_parts_to_buy | description | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | part6 | part6 description | 3 |
| 1 | part10 | part10 description | 1 |
| 1 | part12 | part12 description | 3 |
| 1 | part13 | part13 description | 2 |
| 1 | part14 | part14 description | 2 |
| 1 | part8 | part8 description | 4 |
| 1 | part9 | part9 description | 2 |

Sorry for this very log question.

Comment: I'd love to help.  This sounds like a fun question to help with... But I'll be honest.  I'm super confused.  Try to simplify your question to highlight where you need help.  Also, I don't read Spanish, so I have no idea if I'm missing an important part.  Keep it simple and be clear.

Comment: Hello piRSquared! I will reformat my question to try to be clearer. Thank you very much for being interested in helping.

Comment: Generally, only questions about narrow, specific bugs are allowed here (as Stack Overflow is intended to be a huge FAQ); moreover, questions about how to make code idiomatic are explicitly too opinion-based to be allowed. Our sister site [codereview.se] permits general questions about how to improve already-working code.

Comment: Hello Charles Duffy, it's amazing to know about the Code Review! I didn't know about that! All my doubts I find the answers here on StackOverflow. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this response from Mr. "trincot", founded in the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159484/building-a-bill-of-materials) , my execution time dropped from 7.2s to 0.3s.
Thank you Mr. Charles Duffy and Mr. piRSquared for the help on the comments.

```python
def bom_build(o,p):
    # Create a hash keyed by parts, providing their sub parts as list
    d = dict()
    for [part, subpart] in parts_h:
        if part in d:
            d[part].append(subpart)
        else:
            d[part] = [subpart]

    bom = []

    def recurse(bom, d, serial, part, path, required):
        if part in d:
            for subpart in d[part]:
                nextpath = path + '/' + subpart
                bom.append([serial, part, subpart, nextpath])
                recurse(bom, d, serial, subpart, nextpath, False)
        elif required: # when there are no sub parts
            bom.append([serial, part, None, path])

    for [serial, part] in order:
        recurse(bom, d, serial, part, part, True)

    return bom

order = [['part3','part3']] # Root part to get the BOM
parts_h = [[x['parent'],x['child']] for x in dict_components] # [['parent','child']] list of lists from my components
bom = bom_build(order,parts_h) # Calling the function
print(bom)
```

#### The result:

```
[['part3', 'part3', 'part6', 'part3/part6'],
 ['part3', 'part3', 'part7', 'part3/part7'],
 ['part3', 'part7', 'part8', 'part3/part7/part8'],
 ['part3', 'part7', 'part9', 'part3/part7/part9'],
 ['part3', 'part7', 'part10', 'part3/part7/part10'],
 ['part3', 'part7', 'part11', 'part3/part7/part11'],
 ['part3', 'part11', 'part12', 'part3/part7/part11/part12'],
 ['part3', 'part11', 'part13', 'part3/part7/part11/part13'],
 ['part3', 'part11', 'part14', 'part3/part7/part11/part14']]
```

#### Could someone help me add the description and quantities to the result?

I would like the result in the dictionary, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: An easy (and imho pretty efficient) way to do this is to build a dictionary from part to description by doing `df_itemsM = df_items.set_index('item')['description'].to_dict()` Then depends what you need, but e.g. `[df_itemsM.get([part.split('\')[0],'no description') for part in  order] for order in result]`

Comment: Hi ntg! I am very flattered by your answer! I corrected the result I had posted. There was no ```/x03``` in the result (my mistake). However, I am already applying your tip and if successful I will put it here.

Comment: thanx, should have been split('/') now that i see it:)To see how  `df_itemsM` is used, do e.g. `df_itemsM.get('part1','no description')`

Comment: Hi ntg! Very interesting! Thanks for the tip!